# c++ Inject dll to cmd.exe monitoring commands

Tags: c++, c, hook, setwindowshookex

I try to inject a dll to cmd.exe which will hook the input commands and save them to file.
i managed to do the injection and get some of the info i want using hook on WH_KEYBOARD.

how can i hook the input of cmd.exe process by other way rather then hook keyboard event?

Answer (score 2):

You can look through the WinAPI calls `cmd.exe` makes and find one that takes the command string as argument and hook it, e.g. with [Microsoft Detours](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/detours/). You could also hook `cmd.exe`'s internal functions but this is less portable.

I loaded the `cmd.exe` I have on my Windows system (Windows 10 v1511 x86_64) into [x64dbg](http://x64dbg.com/) and there are two calls to [ReadConsoleW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms684958(v=vs.85).aspx). The first one:

```
Address=00007FF6331A29CC
Disassembly=call qword ptr ds:[<&ReadConsoleW>]
Destination=cmd.&ReadConsoleW
```

is called after processing every command entered via the console.

Per [x64 fastcall convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286(v=vs.100).aspx), its second argument (The buffer) is pointed to by `rdx`. While it's formally an output parameter, prior to calling the function it points to a CRLF terminated copy of the entered command.

You can either hook that call or trace back from there and find a more suitable place to hook.